# GNU parallel: Running tests against a service - Fail early

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am using parallel to parallelize automatic tests against a service as part of a build pipeline.
Essentially, my current approach is to use the following.
In the end, what should happen:

- As soon as both tests are successfully -> success
- As soon as any one of the job fails -> terminate all and return error

However, it currently happens that of course the service runs indefinitely (unless cancelled), so thats why below I put success=2. If a test fails, however, this will never trigger, and thus I had to add a --timeout 120. However, this only leads to the workaround that after a test fails, I have to wait 2 more minutes to received that info.

```html
parallel --halt now,success=2 -j3 ::: start_service.py test1.py test2.py
```

EDIT:
It turns out that parallel per default is installed with 2016xx verison using apt-get. After installing from source on debian buster; I can at least start using the following:

```html
parallel --halt now,done=2 -j3 ::: start_service.py test1.py test2.py
```

However, this returns a non-zero exist status even if the two tests are successful.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking the right thing, but focusing on the wrong conclusion.

Do not focus on success but on failure:

```
start_service.py &
# wait until service is ready then run:
parallel --halt now,fail=1 -j0 ::: test1.py test2.py
# stop service
stop_service.py
```

Comment: This doesn't work if both tests are successful: No job has failed, and the service continues running indefinitely, meaning parallel will never quit, which is obviously bad for builds.

Comment: @Zahlii Did you test? GNU Parallel will stop if one job fails or if all jobs complete succesfully. If you do not see this, then make an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes. The issue is that the service runs forever, so it will never stop - neither successfully, nor unsuccessfully. So if none of the test fails, the service is still running; but since no fail has occurred, parallel won't stop and will continue running forever.

In a way, you can think of the "service" as a "sleep 365d" command, and the tests as more or less instantly returning 0 or 1

Comment: `stop_service.py` will stop the service, when GNU Parallel is done.